# Lots of Lists of Lists - Return only lists that the first index matches

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I have a websocket feed that return lists or lists of lists and I want to pull out only individual lists that meet the criteria that I want.

Example data:

```
[['o', 0, '9726.85438804', '0.40716427']]
[['o', 0, '9909.02930523', '0.00000000'], ['o', 0, '9855.53483394', '12.07669000']]
[['o', 0, '9669.50657753', '0.00000000'], ['o', 0, '9669.60657753', '0.30000000']]
[['o', 1, '9660.00000000', '0.00000000'], ['o', 1, '9658.52360670', '0.00000000'], ['o', 1, '9652.51635910', '0.00000000'], ['o', 1, '9652.50517986', '0.00244445'], ['t', '23068523', 0, '9660.00000000', '0.00191511', 1525594948], ['t', '23068524', 0, '9660.00000000', '0.00160000', 1525594948], ['t', '23068525', 0, '9658.52360670', '0.00020655', 1525594948], ['t', '23068526', 0, '9652.51635910', '0.00020668', 1525594948], ['t', '23068527', 0, '9652.50517986', '0.10115560', 1525594948]]
[['o', 0, '9727.41662891', '0.58301369']]
[['o', 1, '9642.52790569', '0.00000000'], ['o', 1, '9652.52790569', '0.40000000']]
[['o', 1, '9650.82850048', '0.00000000']]
[['o', 0, '9669.60657753', '0.29000000'], ['t', '23068528', 1, '9669.60657753', '0.01000000', 1525594956]]
```

I want to extract/print any sublist that has the first index 't'. So from the above it would return:

```
['t', '23068523', 0, '9660.00000000', '0.00191511', 1525594948]
['t', '23068524', 0, '9660.00000000', '0.00160000', 1525594948]
['t', '23068525', 0, '9658.52360670', '0.00020655', 1525594948]
['t', '23068526', 0, '9652.51635910', '0.00020668', 1525594948]
['t', '23068527', 0, '9652.50517986', '0.10115560', 1525594948]
['t', '23068528', 1, '9669.60657753', '0.01000000', 1525594956]
```

Comment: And where is your code? Hint: `sublst[0] == 't'` is a very good starting point.

Comment: Is that one big list, or eight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple loop

```
for l in nested_list:
    if l[0] == 't':
        print (l)
```

if there is an outer list just add a loop.
one liner with filter

```
filter(lambda x: x[0] == 't', nested_list)
```